# ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref in django virtualenv

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

After upgrading my Ubuntu desktop to 18.04 from 16.04, the django's virtualenv refuses to start:

```
(.djangoenv) mw@desktop:~/theapp$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig   # NOQA
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.exceptions import AppRegistryNotReady, ImproperlyConfigured
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/exceptions.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import Promise
  File "/home/mw/.djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 1, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

On the `djangoenv` and outside it

```
$ python --version : 
`Python 2.7.12`
```

Hoping to resolve the issue, I also install `Python 2.7.16` on the desktop, so I get:

```
$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Also when I try to install new virtualenv, I get the same error:

```
$ virtualenv .blaenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/mw/.djangoenv/bin/python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 21, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Answers to the same error in other contexts did not help and my search led to no more clues.
So really appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per https://askubuntu.com/questions/981663/python2-7-broken-by-weakref-import-error-please-help you probably need to recreate your virtualenv. I suspect your problem here is that you need to `deactivate` your current env before you try to make the new one, in order to ensure that your system python2 interpreter is the one running the virtualenv command.